# Refactoring Promise to Async/wait. Why I got undefiened?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have the code on Promise:

```
function one() {
  return new Promise((rs,er)=>{
  console.log('start');
  new Promise((rr,err)=>{setTimeout(()=>{console.log('after 3 sec');rr()},3000)})
    .then( sd => {
      console.log('endLong');
      rs();
      })
    });
}

one().then(_ => one()).then(_ => one());
```

And as a result I get syncronized code.

But when I refactoring it to async/wait

```
async function one() {
  console.log('start');
  await longtime();
  console.log('endLong');
}

async function longtime() {setTimeout(()=>{console.log('after 3 sec');},3000);}

one().then(_ => one()).then(_ => one())
```

then I got:

```
start
endLong
start
endLong
start
endLong
Promise {<resolved>: undefined}
after 3 sec
after 3 sec
after 3 sec
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need `longtime` to return a *promise*. A `setTimeout` alone does not mean anything to promise-based `async`/`await`:

```js
async function one() {
  console.log('start');
  await longtime();
  console.log('endLong');
}

const longtime = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('after 0.5 sec');
    resolve();
  }, 500);
});

one()
  .then(_ => one())
  .then(_ => one())
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` does not return a promise. An async function should return a promise that's resolved with the value.

```
 function longtime() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('after 3 sec');
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
```

Comment: yeah, but I wrap it with 'async' wich automaticaly should return promise